# How to compile a node.js module myself

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, mongodb

Can someone give me a brief overview of what is involved in compiling a node.js module myself?  I need to use mongodb@1.1.3.  Unfortunately, `npm install mongodb@1.1.3` fails because it has a dependency on bson@0.1.1.  bson@0.1.1 uses `node install`, I am on Xubuntu (Debian), which has changed `node` to `nodejs` because of a namespace collision.

Can I just git clone the module into a directory off of `~/workspace/projectname/node_modules`?  Then modify the offending reference, and voila?

Comment: have you tried doing an alias before npm install? I know it isn't the best solution, but `alias node=nodejs` can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix, you can add a link from `/usr/bin/nodejs` to `$HOME/bin/node` and make sure that `$HOME/bin` is first in your path (it should be):

```
mkdir -p $HOME/bin
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs $HOME/bin/node
hash -r
echo $PATH
```

Afterwards, `node install` should work.